# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined for random quote generator?

Tags: jquery, arrays, random

I have a random quote generator snippet of jQuery code, which is giving me the following console error:

When I click the button it shows the first quote successfully, but then stops.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#change").click(function(){
var quotes = [
  ["It Crowd" ],
  ["Black Books"],
  ["Still Game"],
  ["quote 4"],
];
  // generate random integer< array.length
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()* (quotes.length+1));
//get the elements or just put them in the document write below
var showQuotes = quotes[number][0];
        
  //                      
  jQuery("#quotecontent").fadeOut("medium",function(){
           var newer = jQuery(
             '<div id="content"><p id="quote">'  + showQuotes + '</p></div>' ); 
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(newer);
      jQuery('#quotecontent').fadeIn("medium");
      });                          
      });    
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="quotecontent">
<p id="quote">This is the original quote</p>
</div>
 <div id="btn-container">
<button id="change">Press</button>
      </div>
```

And this is the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I know it relates to this part of the code:

```
var showQuotes = quotes[number][0];
```

But I am just unsure why it wouldn't be working as I am a bit new to arrays. If someone could kindly help me to understand why this isn't working, that would be so appreciated!!!

Codepen if it helps: https://codepen.io/kiaramelissa/pen/XWXqgVa

Comment: A random index of `quotes` is `Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)`, not `Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length + 1))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but no it doesnt... I updated the CodePen with this snippet and it still doesn't work. I tried reading through that thread too but nothing is working?

Comment: You replace your `<div id="quotecontent">` by a `<div id="content">` so jQuery never finds your element again.

Comment: OH MY GOSH. What a stupid oversight. Thank you, this fixed it!!

Comment: just use jQuery(this).html(newer); and remove [0] like answer stated, and I see no errors.

Comment: Your code from Codepen worked fine on Chrome. Not sure which browser are you checking this on. It always helps if you mention the browser used when it's client side issues. 
Another point I wanted to add is that "quotes" is an array of arrays, which is not necessary in this case. Unless you want to store more details for each quote, you could simply use

`var quotes = ["It Crowd", "Black Books", "Still Game","quote 4"];`

and

`var showQuotes = quotes[number];`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the [0] of this line:

```
var showQuotes = quotes[number][0];
```

quotes[number] will return the string stored in that position. With that [0] you will never find anything since quotes[number] it's the final value and not an array.

Edit:

Change:

```
var quotes = [
 ["It Crowd" ],
 ["Black Books"],
 ["Still Game"],
 ["quote 4"],
];
```

To:

```
var quotes = [
  "It Crowd",
  "Black Books",
  "Still Game",
  "quote 4"
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in doing that I still get the same issue